# How to add a views with custom template to the newsletter

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have a newsletter in which I have put a box with the last 3 blogs updated. So far so good using views_embed_view().

The views are there, tried in various ways to create one. Tpl to customize the views andnot none of them worked. I know how to do it did in other parts of the site and it worked. As I was not working I put the html code in Rewrite Results> Rewrite the output of this field of work and Views.

But now I need to add the htmlentities() function to replace special characters with html encode, but you can not do it through views. The views-view - blog-newsletter.tpl.php despite appearing asset information on theming the view is ignored by block the newsletter that goes with the standard html views.

You know how to solve this?